# How do I install an in-house developed Cordova Plugin in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I've been developing a Cordova app (for Android) in Visual Studio 2015 for many months now without any real issues. I've installed plugins, updated my version of Cordova and deployed APKs to devices without issue.

But I now need to write my own plugin to expand on some features we need. The specific features aren't actually important to this question though.

I've been following best I can the following guide:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

I've used PlugMan to create the plugin and add the Android platform like so:

```
plugman create --name DeviceInfo --plugin_id cordova-plugin-mycompany-deviceinfo --plugin_version 0.0.1

plugman platform add --platform_name android
```

I left all the details (more or less) default to keep things as close to the example as possible.

This gave me the following folders and files in a plugin holding project I created in Visual Studio:

[image: Folder Structure of new Cordova Plugin]

I then went to my Cordova project to add the plugin as I normally would (and have done so for many months), but it refuses to add the plugin:

[image: Cordova being mean]

This is the error I'm getting in the Output window of Visual Studio, but I'm pretty sure this is a fairly standard Cordova output which is not VS specific:

```
 Executing "before_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins.
 No version specified, retrieving version from config.xml
 No version given in config.xml, attempting to use plugin engine info
 C:\Users\matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                     throw e;
                           ^
 Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/Application.MyCordovaApplication
```

Here's my plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-mycompany-deviceinfo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <name>DeviceInfo</name>

  <js-module name="DeviceInfo" src="www/DeviceInfo.js">
    <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.DeviceInfo" />
  </js-module>

  <platform name="android">

    <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
      <feature name="DeviceInfo">
        <param name="android-package" value="cordova-plugin-mycompany-deviceinfo.DeviceInfo" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>

    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/DeviceInfo.java" target-dir="src/cordova-plugin-mycompany-deviceinfo/DeviceInfo" />

  </platform>
</plugin>
```

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="com.sample.app" version="2.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US" android-versionCode="2000038">
  <name>My Application</name>
  <description>
  </description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">My Company</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" height="1280" />
  </platform>
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="False" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" version="2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" version="1.2.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="2.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" version="1.0.5" />
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" version="2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.1.4" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" version="1.2.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" version="1.0.5" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.6.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" version="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" version="1.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fastrde-md5" version="0.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" version="2.2.5" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" version="6.0.5" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-networkinterface" version="1.0.8" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetoothle" version="4.3.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" version="0.4.6" />
</widget>
```

It's all rather frustrating.

**So my question, how do I make my plugin install into my Cordova application?**

Comment: Could you please post your `plugin.xml` and your `config.xml` files?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Done!

Comment: Hey I have developed 2 plugins for our Cordova application(using Visual Studio) I just rightclicked my Solution and unter the Tab import Plugin I selected the zip. version of my Plugin this worked flawlessly so far. I am not sure If you have that option available but If yes thats the easiest way

Comment: @stackg91 I don't have any options called that and the plugins aren't zips, they're just folders.

Comment: mh here is a screenshot but I guess you have a different base template or smth https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/B3Y6

Comment: @stackg91 Yeah, it looks like it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/woc6sz7ksy1o598/no-plugin-import.png?dl=0

Comment: @Matthew In plugman create, you have specified plugin id as "cordova-plugin-deviceinfo" but in plugin.xml its mentioned as "cordova-plugin-mycompany-deviceinfo" i guess this could be an issue if its not a typo during your SO post

Comment: @Gandhi Yup! It's a typo, my bad, I'll correct it.

Comment: @Matthew issue remains even after this change?

Comment: @Gandhi It was a typo in my SO post. XD

Comment: @Matthew i guess you have missed out the path atribute in plugman create command. So i feel that the path may be creating the issue. Also in the error trace you mentioned, it tries to connect to "https://registry.npmjs.org/Application.MyCordovaApplication" But i dont see any mention of "MyCordovaApplication" in your config which is fishy.

Comment: @Gandhi That's the name of the VS Cordova application I'm trying to add the plugin too. I have no idea why it would be trying to connect to that URL... it should NEED to connect to ANY URL!

Comment: @Matthew it will try to look for the plugin in the npm local registry. Ideally it should be trying to look for plugin name from the registry not the Cordova application name. In fact you can find all installed plugins in the local npm registry

Comment: @Matthew as a workaround, you can port your plugin to your git repository and install the plugin use the git link in VS. This should work I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135801/discussion-between-matthew-and-gandhi).

Comment: @matthew you can also checkout bitbucket private repository which is more like github but free